# Generic two-dimensional matrix Length(0) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, matrix

I am trying to construct a two-dimensional Matrix where T is number( int, float decimal), but when I try to create a constructor from a two dimensional array T[,] it does not allow me to get Length(0) and Length(1), only Length. I will need then to subtract, multiply and add instances of Matrix, but I can't go through them without the two dimensions.
Compiler error: Method, delegate or event expected. Thanks.

```
using System;
public class Matrix<T>
    where T : struct,
     IComparable<T>, 
     IConvertible, 
     IEquatable<T>, 
     IFormattable
{
    readonly T[,] matr;
    public int rows;

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return rows; }
    }

    public int Cols
    {
        get { return cols; }
    }

    public int cols;

    public Matrix(T[,] table)
    {
        matr = table;
        rows = matr.Length(0);//problem here
        cols = matr.Length(1);//problem here
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matr.GetLength(0)  // -> Gets first dimension size

matr.GetLength(1)  // -> Gets second dimension size
```

Ref. [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but something to think about anyway: Unfortunately, C# doesn't support template arguments to be of "number" type. The following will not compile in your matrix class:

```
 public static Matrix<T> Add(Matrix<T> a, Matrix<T> b)
 {
     Matrix<T> ret;
     for(...)
     {
         ret[i, j] = a[i,j] + b[i, j]; // Error: No operator + defined for type T
     }
 }
```

There's no interface that you could add into your `where` clause to tell the compiler that T must support operator +.

As far as I know, there's only two ways around this: Write three entirely different classes for double, float, integer or use the `dynamic` type. The later gets the nicest code, but may result in a severe performance impact for a math library.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will use dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Matrix<T>
    where T : struct, 
        IComparable<T>,
        IConvertible,
        IEquatable<T>,
        IFormattable
{
    private readonly T[,] matr;
    public int rows;

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return rows; }
    }

    public int Cols
    {
        get { return cols; }
    }

    public int cols;

    public Matrix(T[,] table)
    {
        matr = table;
        rows = matr.GetLength(0);
        cols = matr.GetLength(1);
    }
```

Comment: Adding some explanation instead of just a code extract would be more helpful.

Comment: 10 minutes late is a bit too late, unless you are bringing more to the answers

Comment: The question was answered perfectly by Mitch Wheat.